# Error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I use this pod to show ads in the app: https://cocoapods.org/pods/AdColony

I completed the SDK implementation with no errors.

But I'm getting this error when I try to run the app on the device: (iPhone)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdImpression", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdColony(ADCAdSession.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

What I tried:

- In build settings, set `ARCHS = armv7 armv7s` and `VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64`.
- In build settings, added `$(inherited)` to `Other Linker Flags`.
- In build settings, set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES`.
- Downloaded the pod added to the project manually.
- Checked the minimum deploy target version of the SDK. That fits with the project.
- Unchecked `Parallelize Build` in Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you found a fix?